# syntax highlighting of code snippets in a web page “google-code-prettify” not working with aspx and html code

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, google-code-prettify

i put following lines in header of html

```
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and in html i want to hightlight some html code :

```
<body onload="prettyPrint()">
    <pre class="prettyprint lang-html">

           <input type="button" value="HELLO"/>

</pre>
</body>
```

but i am not unable to hightline html code :
current copy here : http://jsfiddle.net/jTYQk/

Comment: I don't understand, what are you trying to highlight? The Button?

Comment: this line :  <input type="button" value="HELLO"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre element does not stop the browser from rendering internal elements. http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linepar/_PRE.html

By changing your < to `&lt;` and > to `&gt;`, you will get it to render correctly.  Check http://jsfiddle.net/jTYQk/1/ for an example.

OR

You could also wrap your code in  `<xmp></xmp>`. See it at http://jsfiddle.net/jTYQk/2/ .

However, this is not recommended since xmp has been marked obsolete.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp